# Python для программистов

Tags: python, c#, c++, python-3.x

Вопрос в следующем.

я решил немного подучить пайтон. К сожалению, я его знаю довольно посредственно, и во время написания чего нибудь на нём всё время гуглю.

Но для меня python - это далеко не первый язык программирования. То есть, я уже пишу несколько лет (мягко говоря) на C# и C++, трогал PHP (потом мыл руки, с мылом!) , номально там пишу на JS (хотя и ненавижу всей душой) и имею представение о том, что в языках происходит "под капотом": как там работают всякие умные указатели, equals, почему и когда нужны структуры вместо объектов и т.п. Правда, у меня нет опыта работы с чисто функциональными языками, но концепции оттуда выглядят немного знакомыми.

И мне хотелось бы сократить путь: взять какую то книжку, где бует написано "о, управлени памятью работает в питоне так то и так то. А вот в таких то ситуациях сделана нормальная оптимизация хвостовой рекурсии, поэтому не парьтесь, пишите рекурсивные вызовы и всё будет хорошо. А вот здесь синтаксис такойто потому то и потому то"

Но, если я иду и беру курс "для начинающих" на курсере - меня снова там учат складывать строки.  (не объясняя, кстати, говоря, мьтабл строки в питоней или имьтабл).

Если я ввожу запрос "Python для программистов" в поисковике - на меня огромным потоком сыпятся "курсы по питону для начинающих, чайников и тех, кто хочет заработывать по много сотен тысяч в месяц". Информации там новой для меня, в общем, ноль.

Не поможете ли Вы мне найти подходящий источник, который пропускает всю эту шелуху и сразу пишет про концепции языка: как там работает управление памятью, объекты, связывание модулей и т.п.? В общем, чтобы я мог использовать свои знания и заниматься обучением "отталкиваясь от других языков"?

Спасибо.

Comment: Документацию к питону читать не пробовали?

Comment: @user7860670, Я пробовал и читаю. Полезно, лучше многих сайтов, но очень "сухо" и коротковато + где там сравнительные связки с другими языками, например - можете конкретную ссылку дать?

Comment: Хочется новых острых ощущений, ворвитесь в функциональное, "Программирование в Erlang.
Франческо Чезарини", можно прямо как по учебнику, у меня даже в бумаге она есть, купил в Москве на конференции HighLoad++. И складывать строки тоже понравится, ведь в Erlang нет переменных. Но только осторожно, там и до Эликсира не далеко, одно неверное движение и все - ты функциональщик.

Comment: Возможно, стоит посмотреть по запросам "python for c# developers", "python for c++ developers".

Comment: книжка Fluent python

Comment: "Fluent Python" - "К вершинам мастерства", если на русском читать. Я её как раз сегодня просматривал (она у меня отложена на "почитать"), когда ответ писал, и особо не увидел там ссылок на С или детальных диаграмм, что в памяти происходит. Мог пропустить, конечно.

Comment: Я вопрос понимаю так, что автору отсылки к С не самоцель, а один из способов описать питон через сравнение. Диаграммы, кажется, тоже далеко не главное. Главное, это целевая аудитория книги - не новички, для которых не только язык, но и вообще концепции программирования новы, а разработчик, которому нужны важные (возможно необычные) детали языка и продвинутые фишки, описанные без сюсюкания, коротко и по делу. В этом плане fluent python книга хорошая, не идеальная, но лучшее из того, что я знаю (я знаю не много).

Comment: Большое спасибо всем, кто откликнулся, и не только за советы, но и за воспиятие моего вопроса без негативной коннотации. я действительно часто вижу в Питоне разные необычные штуки, такие, как сайд-эффекты обычных логических операторов ("В языке Python операторы and и or, как вы и ожидали, выполняют булевы операции, но они не возвращают булевы значения: результатом всегда является значение одного из операндов"). И, благодаря Вашим советам, постараюсь эти знания как то собрать в одну кучу :-)

Comment: Не знаю, насколько еще актуально, для не "начинающих" посоветовал бы [Python для сетевых инженеров](https://pyneng.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/) и [продолжение](https://advpyneng.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отличный у вас вопрос! Прочитайте первую главу учебника Чернышова "Основы программирования на Python" (он Министерством не зря рекомендован, я специально такой искал). Там "теория", которая должна покрыть часть ваших вопросов и дать толчок мысли, в каком направлении думать дальше. Можете почитать и другие главы, но там уже, скорее, практика, а с седьмой главы начинается просто описание (впрочем, в большинстве мест про многопоточность и т.д. вообще ничего, так что для систематизации седьмая тоже подойдёт).
Западные учебники, что я видел, к сожалению, отражают их подход в стиле "садись и пиши, синтаксис важнее знания "что под капотом".
Остальное советую добирать статьми на habr по интересующим темам и других сайтах в режиме поиска. Англоязычный сегмент значительно более развит.
Если найдёте хороший структурированный источник сами в результате, то обязательно дайте знать ответом тут:-) Мне их сильно не хватает. Писал когда-то на С достаточно хорошо, и изучение Python на уровне синтаксиса и примеров несколько разочаровывает.
Надо учесть, что Python сильно развился с точки зрения популярности (на мой взгляд) за счёт "лучший стиль - взять framework, обвешать чужими библиотеками, как-то запустить (задав кучу вопросов на SO), и ты - тру эксперт в биг дата", так что и материалы на соответствующую аудиторию в большинстве своём.
Учтите, что это соображения человека, Python пару месяцев изучающего. Возможно, более опытные люди дадут что-то более полезное:-)

Дополнение:
Вот пример интересной статьи на habr (она про GIL, советую ознакомиться, затрагивает важные вещи, относящиеся к языку, и достаточно глубокая):
https://habr.com/ru/company/wunderfund/blog/586360/

Comment: Большое спасибо, отличный совет! Може, прочитав, даже напишу в комментариях впечатления